Can one determine openness by only looking at openness in two closed subspace whose union is the whole space?
The motivition of my question is quite intuitive: if I cut a piece of paper into two halves and then glue them by the cut, it's natural to expect the identification space homeomorphic to the original space.
More precisely, given a topological space $X$ and two closed sets $A$ and $B$ whose union is $X$. Now construct the disjoint union $A\sqcup B$ and we have the natural map $f: A\sqcup B\to X$ induced by the inclusion maps of $A$ and $B$. We define a equivalence relation on $A\sqcup B$ by $x\sim y$ iff $f(x) = f(y)$. I wonder whether $A\sqcup B/\sim $ is homeomorphic to $X$.
I think this is equivalent to saying $f$ is a quotient map. Actually, it's easy to see $f$ is surjective and continuous. Thus we just need to prove that, if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A\sqcup B$, then $U$ is open in $X$. That is simply what I am asking in the title. And note that the closedness condition may be replaced by openness but cannot be dropped, as the case $\mathbb{R} =\mathbb{Q} \sqcup (\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q})$ suggests.

[UPDATE]
It's so nice to see my question solved quickly. Thanks everyone!
I would like to share an elegant application of this property. I was trying to prove $\mathbb{D}^2/\sim$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$ where equivalence on boundary is defined axisymetrically:$(x,y)\sim (-x,y)$. I prefer to call such a quotient space a "dumpling" since I locate in east Asia. It's almost geometrically obvious so that some books didn't provide a rigorous proof, while some of the others (J. Lee for example) straightforwardly gave a complicated function.
My thought: first, cut the dumpling by the "seam" and the y-axis of the disc, obtaining two disjoint semi-discs; then, cut the sphere into two semi-spheres. It's much easier to see a semi-disc is homeomorphic to a full disc and subsequently to a semi-sphere. By proper arrangement we can let the homeomorphism take "seam" to "seam", homeomorphically. With our property, we can paste by the seam and claim the homeomorphism will be inherited. Of course some detail is omitted but I think the hardest part has been done.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

I think your definition is not exactly right, better introduce the inclusions maps of $A$ and $B$. Your question however seems to be equivalent to: is a cocartesian square always Cartesian in the category of topological spaces?

I'm a bit confused. I understand the disjoint union construction is indeed the coproduct in Top category but I have no idea about what is a "cartesian" space (or object in category).  Set-theoretically, disjoint union is of course not a Cartesian product, however. And, an inclusion map is just the map $p: A\to X, x\mapsto x$ .

Since $A, B$ are closed, $f$ is closed, hence a quotient map.

Yes. This is true. Indeed, $U \cap A$ being open in $A$ implies there is an open $V \subset X $ s.t. $U \cap A = V \cap A$. Similarly, there is an open $W \subset X$ s.t. $U \cap B = W \cap B$. Now,
$$U \setminus B = (U \cap A) \setminus B = (V \cap A) \setminus B = V \setminus B$$
is open since $B$ is closed. Similarly, $U \setminus A = W \setminus A$ is open. Finally, consider $V \cap W$, which is open. We have,
$$\begin{split}
V \cap W &= V \cap W \cap (A \cup B)\\
&= (V \cap W \cap A) \cup (V \cap W \cap B)\\
&= (W \cap U \cap A) \cup (V \cap U \cap B)\\
&\subset U
\end{split}$$
And furthermore,
$$(V \cap W) \cap (A \cap B) = (U \cap A) \cap (U \cap B) = U \cap (A \cap B)$$
So, in particular $U \cap (A \cap B) \subset V \cap W$. Thus, we have $(U \setminus B) \cup (U \setminus A) \cup (V \cap W)$ is open and is contained in $U$. Conversely,
$$U = (U \setminus B) \cup (U \setminus A) \cup (U \cap (A \cap B)) \subset (U \setminus B) \cup (U \setminus A) \cup (V \cap W)$$
That is, $U = (U \setminus B) \cup (U \setminus A) \cup (V \cap W)$ is open.

Thanks. I feel this approach more direct and visual. The beautiful idea is to break it into union of three easy-to-verify open sets.

What you want to show is that if $U \cap A$ is open in $A$ and $U \cap B$ is open in $B$, then $U$ is open in $X$.
Let us first prove that if $U \cap A$ is closed in $A$ and $U \cap B$ is closed in $B$, then $U$ is closed in $X$. Since closed subsets of closed subspaces are closed in the full space, $U \cap A$ and $U \cap B$ are closed in $X$. Hence $U = U \cap A \cup U \cap B$ is closed in $X$.
This shows that your map $f$ is a quotient map. Indeed quotient maps $p : Z  \to Y$ can alternatively be characterized as surjections such that $M \subset Y$ is closed in $Y$ iff $p^{-1}(M)$ is closed in $Z$ (consider complements to check that a map with this property is a quotient map).
Anyway, the complement approach applies directly for your question. If $U \cap A$ is open in $A$ and $U \cap B$ is open in $B$, then $(X \setminus U) \cap A = A \setminus (U \cap A)$ is closed in $A$ and $(X \setminus U) \cap B = B \setminus (U \cap B)$ is closed in $B$, hence $X \setminus U  =(X \setminus U) \cap A \cup (X \setminus U) \cap B$ is closed in $X$ and $U$ is open in $X$.

Thanks for help. If still interested, I updated an interesting application in the description.
